# How do I plot the PDF of a Mixed distribution with the following parameters?

Tags: scripting

```
m = FindDistribution[d2, 1]

MixtureDistribution[{0.719504,0.280496}, {NormalDistribution[-4.85601, 2.63207], NormalDistribution[-2.7934, 0.845561]}]
```

I need to create a PDF and a CDF plot of the Mixed with the following parameters mentioned above.

Comment: What's `m`? What's `d2`? What does the first line have to do with the 2nd line?

Comment: Please do not fundamentally alter your question after getting an answer to it. Not only is it impolite to the people who spent time answering your original question, it makes it difficult for future readers to get useful information out of the existing answers. If you have follow up questions, open a new question. At this point it is too late to revert your question as you have an answer to the new question, but in the future follow these guidelines.

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. One weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 3):

Amplifying on [`Henrik Schumacher's`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher) answer/comments; you use a [`MixtureDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixtureDistribution.html) the same as you would any other distribution.

```
dist = MixtureDistribution[{0.719504, 
    0.280496}, {NormalDistribution[-4.85601, 2.63207], 
    NormalDistribution[-2.7934, 0.845561]}];

{mean, var, sd, med} = #[dist] & /@ {Mean, Variance, StandardDeviation, Median}

(* {-4.27746, 6.04373, 2.4584, -3.82853} *)

mode = x /. 
  NSolve[{D[PDF[dist, x], x] == 0, D[PDF[dist, x], {x, 2}] < 0}, x, 
    Reals][[1]]

(* -2.92044 *)

#[dist, x] & /@ {PDF, CDF}

(* {0.13234 E^(-0.699327 (2.7934 + x)^2) + 
  0.109055 E^(-0.0721731 (4.85601 + x)^2), 
 0.359752 Erfc[0.26865 (-4.85601 - x)] + 
  0.140248 Erfc[0.836258 (-2.7934 - x)]} *)
```

**EDIT:** The `PDF` of the [`MixtureDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MixtureDistribution.html) is the weighted sum of the `PDF`s of the underlying [`NormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html)s

```
PDF[dist, x] -
 (dist[[1, 1]]*PDF[dist[[-1, 1]], x] +
   dist[[1, 2]]*PDF[dist[[-1, 2]], x])

(* 0. *)

SeedRandom[0];
sample = RandomVariate[dist, 1000];

Show[Histogram[sample, Automatic, "PDF"], Plot[{PDF[dist, x],
   dist[[1, 1]]*PDF[dist[[-1, 1]], x],
   dist[[1, 2]]*PDF[dist[[-1, 2]], x]},
  {x, Min[sample], Max[sample]},
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dotted, Dashed},
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.275, 0.75}]],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**END EDIT**

```
Show[
 Histogram[sample, Automatic, "CDF"],
 Plot[CDF[dist, x], {x, Min[sample], Max[sample]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
distro = ParetoDistribution[524051., 2.8772, 1.58999, 0.799873];
Plot[
 PDF[distro][x],
 {x, distro[[-1]], 100}
 ]
Plot[
 CDF[distro][x],
 {x, distro[[-1]], 100}
 ]
```

Comment: what about the -13.0934? what does that mean?

Comment: Should be the `"LogLikelihood"`. Quite small, isn't it?

Comment: @H_hazard [read the manual](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html#1782772375), dude

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher `LogLikelihood` is inversely proportional to data size. Even a moderately large dataset will give you that.

Comment: I had another question. Could you please read the question. I have updated it as follows

Comment: @H_hazard My friend, that's not the way it's supposed to work on this site. If you have a new question, please open a new post. It is extremely frustrating when the goal of a post gets changed after an answer was provide.

Comment: Anyways, just use `PDF` and `CDF` along with `Plot` on `MixtureDistribution[...]`, similar to the answer I gave.

Comment: I did - that didn't work

Comment: Sorry about the trouble

Comment: mixture is the result of two normal distributions. How do I show that on plot?

Comment: `Plot[
 PDF[
   MixtureDistribution[{0.719504, 0.280496},
    {
     NormalDistribution[-4.85601, 2.63207],
     NormalDistribution[-2.7934, 0.845561]
     }]][x],
 {x, -10, 10}
 ]`?